# Count all occurrences of a tag in lots of log files using grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to get the quantity of tags, for example "103=16" found in lots of files, how many of them are, but  only the files that have one or more occurrences

I'm using:

```
find . /opt/FIXLOGS/l51prdsrv\* -iname "TRADX\_*oe*.log" -type f -exec grep -F 103=16 -c {} /dev/null ;
```

which finds the file where the tag is and shows the number of matches, but it also shows the 0 occurrences

returns

file1.log:0

file2.log:0

file3.log:6

file4.log:0

using a -i to exclude the 0 or grep -v :0 haven't worked for me, gets the result:

grep: :0: No such file or directory

How can I get only the files where the count is more than 0?

Comment: Does this work? ```find . /opt/FIXLOGS/l51prdsrv* -iname "TRADX_oe.log" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -F 103=16 -c | grep -v ':0$'```

Comment: I don't understand your question at all, but I think you maybe need `grep -m1` which quits after the first match.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, at the end what worked was find . -type f -iname "TRADX_oe.log" -exec grep -cFH "103=16" {} \; | grep -v ":0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried piping into grep to negate the ones with zeroes after the find/exec?

E.g., like this works for me:

```bash
find . -type f -iname "TRADX_oe.log" -exec grep -cFH "103=16" {} \; | grep -v ":0"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, i tried piping it but the problem was i was doing it ehind the ; and not putting the 0 in quotes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` to do everything in one place

```
find . -type f -iname "TRADX_oe.log" -exec awk '/103=16/{c++} END { if(c)print FILENAME, c}' {} \;
```

Comment: This worked as well, is something that i didn't know i could use, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is the way how `-c` option of grep works:

> -c, --count
> Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file.  With the -v, --invert-match
> option (see below), count non-matching lines.

So it will print 0 counts, only option is to remove 0 with another grep using `-v` or use awk:

```
awk '/search_pattern/{f[FILENAME]+=1} END {for(i in f){print i":"f[i]}}' /path/to/files*
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i pipe the grep after the ; excluding the zero  | grep -v ":0"

ending like this:

find .  route -iname "TRAD_*oe*.log" -type f  -exec grep -cHF "103=16" {} ; | grep -v ":0"

Comment: I recommend visiting [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so your answer can be properly formatted.